# Ошибка: "Could not open a connection to SQL Server"

Tags: sql-server, sql

Здравствуйте.

Запускаю Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, хочу соединиться с сервером такой ошибку дает:

> `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, ошибка: 2)`

Что делать?

Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Comment: скорее за все у вас или сервер не запущен или у него не запущен TCP/IP листенер. попробуйте сделать telnet <ip> 1433 (стандартный порт) если не коннектится то скорее за все так и есть. гуглить "MS SQL enable tcp listening"

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я все это попробовал, все равно не запустилось,но проблема решена, новый пакет скачал и все хорошо, нормально установилось и запускается проблема было за пакетом.